# Vector integration of a multivariate function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

How can the following integral be evaluated using Mathematica,

$\int_{\beta} \frac{1}{\left(||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{D\beta}||^2 + \gamma\right)^{\alpha}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\beta^T\Sigma^{-1}\beta\right) \mathrm{d}\beta$,

where $\mathbf{\beta}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are vectors of sizes $M\times 1$ and $N\times1$ respectively, $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ are matrices of respective sizes that allow the combination with vectors, $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are positive integers and $||\cdot||$ denote the $\ell_2$ norm ?

Comment: I dont know if Mathematica will be able to do this independently of the dimensions $M$ and $N$. You can begin to build up your integration with `M = 4; b = Array[bc, M]; int = Integrate[Exp[-b.b], b]` and taking a look at `Assuming`.

Comment: Did you try to perform the usual analytic tricks like diagonalizing $\Sigma^{-1}$, transforming the integral measure and so on?

Comment: @MauricioLobos: Indeed, building up seems to be a better approach.

Comment: @marmot: Yes, I am trying with the simplest case of $\Sigma$ being the identity matrix, but it seems taking quite long time, and not yet converging to a closed form. However, I am a tenderfoot in making Mathematica evaluate these kind of integrals.

Comment: @ArunM I guess this is more a maths than a mathematica problem since you can cook down the integral quite a bit by diagonalizing $\Sigma^{-1}$, i.e. $\Sigma^{-1}=U^T\cdot S\cdot U$ where $S$ is diagonal and positive (such that the integral converges), redefining $\beta$, $\beta'=\sqrt{S}\cdot U\cdot\beta$, and then` diagonalizing' $D$ in the $\beta'$ basis. I know that these steps are described in most of the literature on path integrals.

Comment: @marmot: Indeed. Thanks. However, if the integral is evaluated for the simplest case of the $\Sigma$ being the identity, then the rest follows. But when I input the vectors as Mauricio suggested, the output I am getting is an expanded version of the integral without doing any calculation. So I am afraid how to do even for a simplest vector case.

Comment: @ArunM : I agree that the 1-dimensional version of the integral causes some problems. The only point I have is that you can cook your integral down to a product of simpler 1-dimensional integrals. My first transformation  above eliminates $\Sigma^{-1}$ at the expense of a factor $\sqrt{\det\Sigma}$. The next step is to use `SingularValueDecomposition[D]` and to perform the corresponding second redefinition of $\beta$. You are then left with the above-mentioned 1-dimensional integrals. I recommend to post these as a question, maybe someone knows how to evaluate them.